# Store Account Id for Google Analytics in Web.config (MVC 3)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, google-analytics

I have this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
</script>
```

How do I store my account id in web.config? **And**
 how can I get it back from web.config to js (instead of writting the id directly)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is no structured way to do it,I just called it from web.config (without using any action, but simply write it) like that:

in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="GoogleAnalyticsAccountId" value="UA-11111111-1" />
</appSettings>
```

in js:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAnalyticsAccountId"]']);
```

Answer (score 1):

write an `ActionResult` to return your id

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAnalyticId(){
var id = ConfigutationManager.ApplicationSetting["analyticID"].ToString();
return Content(id);
}
```

in your javascript

```
$.post("/Controller/GetAnalyticId",function(data){
//data contains the id use it where you want to
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

});
```